# Vue.JS Vuex store and accessing my api through dependency injection

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm having difficulties accessing my api within my store modules. I've created an instance of my api, passed it within my vue creation just like the store. However when trying to implement logic in my module, the this.$api does not work like it works in my components. Is there any way to access my already created instance of api?

```
const api = new Api();


/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
    components: {App},
    router,
    api,               // <--- I want this.
    store,             // <--- To be accesable in the modules of this
    template: '<App/>'
}).$mount('#app');
```

So can I access the api instance without creating a new instance in my module or store?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should be able to inject api directly to store, like this:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store();
const $axios = axios.create();
store.$axios = $axios;
new Vue({
  components: {App},
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>'
}).$mount('#app');
```

Anyways, for Axios, it worked fine: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/accessing-axios-in-vuex-module/29414/3

Comment: Thanks! By creating and api-instance.js file and exporting an $api instance from there I am able to import ONE instance of the api anywhere!

Comment: What about with typescript? You cannot just add random properties with TS enabled...